# K8s inter service communication timeout

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, flannel, coredns, kube-proxy

We have a K8s Cluster (3 Master - 2 Worker) - v1.17

There are 2 Microservice in this cluster, a Microservices A call to Common.
Sometimes, I face the problem is: A call to Common has timeout after 60s - Although this request is processed very quickly in the Common and success ( < 10ms).

```
getErrorInfoFallback : feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET http://common-service.dev.svc.cluster.local:8002/errormapping/v1.0?errorCode=abcxyz
```

I use FeignClient to call other Microservice with url like http://common-service.dev.svc.cluster.local:8002

```
Here is timeline:
- 16:37:42.362 A send request 
- 16:37:42.368 Common logging the request 
- 16:37:42.378 Common logging respone return 
- 16:38:42.424 A: timeout exeption
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: How many pods are under service Common? Maybe port is being used or load on the pod under the service is high?

Comment: There are 4 pods of Common, 2 pods of A Service. I only testing with 20 concurent threads by jmetter. I was update the timeline, It's seem the request send to Common successful but response is not OK.

Comment: Have you checked metrics inside the `pod`? Also how exactly are you testing it and which CNI are you using?

Comment: It's me. CNI is flannel, I have take tcp dump and found a lot of TCP packet retranmission, and then TCP connection has been closed after some retry.